# Is there any way to get all calendar (cross by account) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

If on my device i have several account (example 1 iCloud account, 1gmail account and 1exchange account) is possibile to get events for all accounts?

I have tried to search but i only found reply related to iCloud account, so i think this is not possible.

Someone have some documentation at regard or had implemented this in the pass?

Comment: Have you looked at the EventKit framework documentation?

Comment: Yes, but isn't clear if it's possible have access to all account's calendar or only to icloud calendars.

Comment: You can access all of the users calendars. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507128-calendars

Comment: Me to need same requirement, i need to fetch calendar events by particular mail account, but no clear document related.